# Get value from select record in store

Tags: extjs, store

Hello I'm have store and I want get value in field `ID` from this store.

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('price gridpicker[name=price]')[0].store.getAt(0).data.id;
```

But this output only ID from first record in store, and when select other record I will still get  ID from first record, help me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the selected record then you need to query the `grid`, not the store.  The store just contains the data, it doesn't know what's going on on the screen.

`Ext.ComponentQuery.query('price gridpicker[name=price]')[0].getGrid().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].get('id');`

Answer (score 1):

The correct call is:

```
...getAt(0).get('id);
```

or, if you want all record's data then

```
...getAt(0).getData();
```

Of course, you can get also other values but you need to know which record is selected by the `gridpicker`.